# Is there an idiomatic way to implement the component pattern?

Tags: rust

Basically a object (struct) is constructed by composing different components. Each concrete component being easily swapped by another component matching the interface (I guess trait).

I'm currently trying to implement with traits which got me into some errors and made me start thinking if this is a common thing in Rust.

```rust
// usage example
fn main() {
    let obj = MainObject::new(Component1::new(), Component2::new(), Component3());
    // Where each component is a type(struct) with some well predefined methods.
}
```

The main idea behind this is to implement the Component pattern commonly used in games. Basically the game would contain a lot of different objects, with slight variations in behavior and contained data. Instead of having a big class hierarchy, the objects are composed of standard components, more complete example would be.

```rust
pub struct Container
{
   input: InputHandlerComponent, // Probably a trait
   physics: PhysicsComponent,  // Probably a trait
   renderer: RendererCompoent // Probably a trait
}

impl Container {
  fn new(p: PhysicsComponent, i: InputComponent, r: RenderComponent) -> Container {
    Container {input: i, physics: p, renderer: r}
 }
}

struct ConcretePhysicsComponent;
impl PhysicsComponent for ConcretePhysicsComponent
{
  // ...
}

struct ConcreteInputComponent;
impl InputComponent for ConcreteInputComponent
{
  // ...
}

struct ConcreteRendererComponent;
impl RendererComponent for ConcreteRendererComponent
{
  // ...
}

struct AnotherConcreteRendererComponent;
impl RendererComponent for AnotherConcreteRendererComponent
{
  // ...
}

// usage example
fn main() {
    let obj = Container::new(ConcreteInputComponent::new(), ConcretePhysicsComponent::new(), ConcreteRendererComponent::new());
    // Where each component is a type(struct) with some well predefined methods.

    // This is a slightly modified version of this object, with changed rendering behaviour
    let obj2 = Container::new(ConcreteInputComponent::new(), ConcretePhysicsComponent::new(), AnotherConcreteRendererComponent::new());    }
```

Comment: Added a more detailed description of what i'm going for. I have a feeling it should be possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you are just asking about traits, multiple concrete implementations of that trait, and a wrapper object that restricts itself to types that implement that trait. Optionally, the container can implement the trait by delegating it to the inner object.

```
trait Health {
    fn life(&self) -> u8;
    fn hit_for(&mut self, lost_life: u8);
}

#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone)]
struct WimpyHealth(u8);
impl Health for WimpyHealth {
    fn life(&self) -> u8 { self.0 }
    fn hit_for(&mut self, lost_life: u8) { self.0 -= lost_life * 2; }
}

#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone)]
struct BuffHealth(u8);
impl Health for BuffHealth {
    fn life(&self) -> u8 { self.0 }
    fn hit_for(&mut self, lost_life: u8) { self.0 -= lost_life / 2; }
}

#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone)]
struct Player<H> {
    health: H,
}

impl<H> Health for Player<H>
    where H: Health
{
    fn life(&self) -> u8 { self.health.life() }
    fn hit_for(&mut self, lost_life: u8) { self.health.hit_for(lost_life) }
}

fn main() {
    let mut player_one = Player { health: WimpyHealth(128) };
    let mut player_two = Player { health: BuffHealth(128) };

    player_one.hit_for(12);
    player_two.hit_for(12);

    println!("{:?}", player_one);
    println!("{:?}", player_two);
}
```

> it is not possible to have an array of such Players without using Boxed values

That's correct. An array or vector (or any generic type, really) needs to all be of the *same* type. This is especially important for arrays/vectors because their memory layout is contiguous and each item needs to be at a fixed interval.

If you were allowed to have different types, then you could have one player that had a health that took 1 byte and another player with health that took 2 bytes. Then all the offsets would be incorrect.

You can implement the `Health` trait for a `Box<Health>`, and then the `Player` objects can be stored sequentially, but they would each have a pointer to the appropriate concrete implementation of `Health` via the box.

```
impl<H: ?Sized> Health for Box<H>
    where H: Health
{
    fn life(&self) -> u8 { (**self).life() }
    fn hit_for(&mut self, lost_life: u8) { (**self).hit_for(lost_life) }
}

fn main() {
    let mut players = vec![
        Player { health: Box::new(WimpyHealth(128)) as Box<Health> },
        Player { health: Box::new(BuffHealth(128)) as Box<Health> }
    ];

    for player in players.iter_mut() {
        player.hit_for(42);
    }

    println!("{:?}", players[0].life());
    println!("{:?}", players[1].life());
}
```

Comment: Actually I've stumbled upon an issue with this approach. As far as I understand is not possible to have an array of such Players without using Boxed values. For example `let arr = vec![Player { health: WimpyHealth(128) }, Player { health: BuffHealth(128) }];` would fail because the the first player instance and the second one have different types.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to store each component contiguously in an array, will a Vec<Box<Player>> store the Players next to each other on the heap? I'll look for the answer myself, but i'll leave this question here, for context.

Comment: @6D65 not necessarily, to do this sort of thing (contiguous component storage in a vector) you're going to have to either use a big enum for your components or resort to things like mem::transmute and other unsafe features.

Comment: @Jsor yeah. i'm just thinking to go the C way to have an array for each type of Component. The entity would be an index into these arrays. Will have to think how to make it less ugly. This will probably help with having a contiguous array.